# A "borrowed value does not live long enough" compiler error for serde Deserialize generic

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Why does `f1()` compile but `f2()` does not?

```
fn f1() {
    let s_json = "[]".to_string();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let ve: Vec<Rec1> = serde_json::from_str(&s_json).unwrap();
    }
}

fn f2<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>() {
    let s_json = "[]".to_string();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let ve: Vec<T> = serde_json::from_str(&s_json).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
| fn fff2<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>() {
|         -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
|         let ve: Vec<T> = serde_json::from_str(&s_json).unwrap();
|                          ---------------------^^^^^^^-
|                          |                    |
|                          |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
|                          argument requires that `s_json` is borrowed for `'a`
|     }
| }
| - `s_json` dropped here while still borrowed
```

What am I doing wrong? What would be the correct `f2()` signature?

Comment: Can't you write `let s_json = "[]"; ... serde_json::from_str(s_json)`? Or is your real JSON value more interesting than a literal "[]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) seems to be provided just for that purpose - to avoid the need for a lifetime.
I guess there is no way to provide a shorter lifetime in `f2()`, but `f1()` somehow doesn't have such a limitation.

Comment: The problem with the shorter lifetime in `f2` is that the provided `'a` will necessarily be longer than the life of the local `s_json`, and what happens when the `s_json` goes out of scope? The storage for your deserialized object disappears!

Comment: And in my example I obviously don't need such a long lifetime, since `ve` gets dropped immediately (at the end of each loop iteration). But I guess there is no way to declare that with standard lifetime declarations.

Comment: Ah, I see where you are now. You want the user of this function to be able to specify the type of `T` but use it with some lifetime local to this function, not external to the function. You write that as `T: for <'a> Deserialize<'a>`, that happens to be a synonym of `DeserializeOwned` you are already using.